# Project Euler #49 Java

Tags: java, permutation, primes

The question is -

> The arithmetic sequence, 1487, 4817, 8147, in which each of the terms
>   increases by 3330, is unusual in two ways: (i) each of the three terms
>   are prime, and, (ii) each of the 4-digit numbers are permutations of
>   one another.
>
> There are no arithmetic sequences made up of three 1-, 2-, or 3-digit
>   primes, exhibiting this property, but there is one other 4-digit
>   increasing sequence.
>
> What 12-digit number do you form by concatenating the three terms in
>   this sequence?

I've written this code -

```
package Problems;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Pro49 {

    private static boolean isPrime(int n){
        if(n%2 == 0) return false;

        for(int i = 3; i<= Math.sqrt(n); i++){
            if(n%i == 0) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isPerm(int m, int n){
        ArrayList<Integer> mArr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> nArr = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            mArr.add(m%10);
            m /= 10;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            nArr.add(n%10);
            n /= 10;
        }

        return mArr.containsAll(nArr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> primes = new LinkedList<>();

        for(int i = 1001; i<10000; i++){
            if(isPrime(i)) primes.add(i);
        }


        int k = 0;
        boolean breaker = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<primes.size() - 2; i++){
            for(int j = i + 1; j<primes.size() - 1; j++){
                if(isPerm(primes.get(i), primes.get(j))) {
                    k = primes.get(j) + (primes.get(j) - primes.get(i));

                    if(k<10000 && primes.contains(k) && isPerm(primes.get(i), k)) {
                        System.out.println(primes.get(i) + "\n" + primes.get(j) + "\n" + k);
                        breaker = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(breaker) break;
            }
            if(breaker) break;
        }


    }

}
```

I added the print line `System.out.println(primes.get(i) + "\n" + primes.get(j) + "\n" + k);` to check the numbers. I got 1049, 1499, 1949 which are wrong. (At least 1049 is wrong I guess).

Can any one point out where my code/logic is wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Concatenating doesn't involve newlines

Comment: @1blustone Yeah, I know that. I just wanted to see which numbers are produced as output that's why I added `\n`. Just to check whether permutations are produced as output or not.

Comment: Here is a somewhat performance boosted version that first collect prime numbers consisting of same digits, *before* looking for equidistant numbers: [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qCjHsf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think where your logic is going wrong is your `isPerm` method. You are using [`AbstractCollection#containsAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which, AFAIK, **only checks if the parameters are in the collection at least once**.

i.e. it basically does

```
for(E e : collection)
    if(!this.contains(e)) return false;
return true;
```

Therefore, for example, 4999 will be a permutation of 49 because 49 contains 4 and 9 (while it is clearly not based on your example).

---

The reason why your method seems to work for these values is that you are looping a fixed amount of time - that is, 4. For a number like 49 you will end up with `{9, 4, 0, 0}` instead of `{9, 4}`. Do something like this:

```
while(n != 0) {
    nArr.add(n%10);
    n /= 10;
}
```

and you will get the correct digit `List`s (and see that `containsAll` won't work.)

Add the 4-digit restriction elsewhere (e.g. in your loop.)

---

Maybe you could check the occurrences per digit.
For example:

```
int[] occurrencesA = new int[10], occurrencesB = new int[10];
for(; m != 0; m /= 10)
    occurrencesA[m % 10]++;
for(; n != 0; n /= 10)
    occurrencesB[n % 10]++;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if(occurrencesA[i] != occurrencesB[i]) return false;
return true;
```

Comment: I thought the same and checked my `isPerm(int n)` But it is giving me the right answer. I even checked now with your example (4999, 49) and it is giving me the correct answer that they are not permutations.

Comment: I noticed it now that `isPerm(4999, 49)` gives out false but `isPerm(999, 99)` gives true and then again `isPerm(9999,99)` gives out false. Pretty weird.

Comment: Yeah, what you said is correct but it shouldn't be an issue, at least in this context because my **primes** list contains only 4-digit prime numbers.

Comment: @SreevathsaGowru wrote a possible replacement for `isPerm`.

Comment: Yeah, It is working. Looks like I've to check the documentation for **containsAll** . Anyways Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible alternative for `isPerm`

```
private static boolean isPerm(int m, int n){
        ArrayList<Integer> mArr = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> nArr = new ArrayList<>();

        final String mS = Integer.toString(m);
        final String nS = Integer.toString(n);

        if(mS.length() != nS.length()) return false;

        for(int i = 0; i<mS.length(); i++){
            mArr.add(m%10);
            m /= 10;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<nS.length(); i++){
            nArr.add(n%10);
            n /= 10;
        }

        return (mArr.containsAll(nArr) && nArr.containsAll(mArr));
    }
```

This is giving me the correct answer. Another alternative is posted by some other person below.

Comment: If you're going to use strings, then you might as well just use `toCharArray` instead of using them as numbers again.